# how to enter a bias for a graph in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to plot a couple of variables on one figure. Each of them I want to give some 'bias' on the y axis, for example: variable a begins in point (0,0), variable b in (0,-10), c (0,-20). How can I define this bias value on y axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add 0, -10 or -20 to the values of your variables.

Comment: If the original functions don't begin at `(0,0)` you might want to subtract the difference between the original first point of each vector and your desired first point from the entire thing.  Say `b = [-15 -20 -25];` but you wanted `b` to start at `(0,-10)`: subtract `(-15 - -10) = -5` from `b` before plotting.